# java/swing: showing potential drop target rows in a JTable

Tags: swing, drag-and-drop, jtable

I want to implement DropTargetListener with a JTable as a target. This is roughly what I would like to do:

```
@Override public void dragOver(DropTargetDragEvent event) {
    MyItem item = getMyItemFromTransferable(); 
    int nrows = item.getTableRowsRequiredForDrop();
    // now highlight rows in the table under the drop cursor.
}
```

How can I figure out which row in the JTable is the row under the cursor where the DropTargetDragEvent is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it would be:

```
int row = myTable.rowAtPoint(event.getLocation());
```